# Check if selected value is null and return it as bit in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a simple query that is grouping some data and returns a value, on code site all what I am doing is check if value is empty or not. But i thought I can get that value without using checking for null on backend just return is null true or false bit. And here the problems start I am not sure if I can do it, or even how. SO let us say I have simple select with grouping:

```
select 
max(some_string_column) // is null not working
from table
group by grouping_value
```

So here I want to check string column value, but they can all be null. So i need to check if this group has any value or is null and return true or false. Now is it possible?

Comment: Use a `CASE` expression or `IIF` (which is a short-hand `CASE` expression).

Comment: *"`// is null not working`"* What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an error? Unexpected results? Undesired behaviour? Something else? Demonstrate your attempt using `IS NULL` and *explain* why it "isn't working".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just cast the count to a `bit`. Non-zeroes become `1`, and `COUNT` only counts non-null values. Then [invert it using `~`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-not-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

```sql
SELECT
  grouping_value,
  ~CAST(COUNT_BIG(some_string_column) AS bit) AS is_null_bit
FROM table
GROUP BY grouping_value;
```

Comment: For reference on the tilde (`~`): [~ (Bitwise NOT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-not-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to use a switch case here.

```sql
SELECT grouping_value,
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(some_string_column) IS NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS is_null_bit
FROM table
GROUP BY grouping_value;
```

Comment: probably also want `CAST(... as bit)`

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is:

```
SELECT MAX(ISNULL(CAST([some_string_column] as int), 0)) AS [max_value]
  FROM yourtable
```

Because you implied you need to convert a string to an integer (which may or may not work), then if the column is null you want this replaced as 0.

`ISNULL()` returns the specified value IF the expression is NULL, otherwise it returns the expression.  Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Another possibility is `TRY_CAST()`, which will try to convert the provided expression to the requested data type. If the conversion succeeds, it will return the expression value after conversion. If an error occurs, it will return NULL value.  In that case you could replace the NULL to 0.

That would be:

```
SELECT MAX(ISNULL(TRY_CAST([some_string_column] as int), 0)) AS [max_value]
  FROM yourtable
```